# Django looks for media files in wrong directory with DEBUG = False and Nginx

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

My 2 Django apps are running with Nginx and Gunicorn on **mysite.com** and **mysite.com/app2**.

**App1**'s media files are working just fine. And for the **app2** with ***DEBUG=False*** I get 404 when trying to download a media file, though the url it makes for the file is correct (it matches the directory on the server).

From *nginx* error log I found that it is probably looking for it in the media directory of **app1**.

How can I make **app2** look for media in the correct directory?

**Nginx log error**:

*2020/06/09 13:24:51 [error] 9378#9378: *1 open() "/home/user/app1/media/attach_1/attach.pdf" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 134.94.7.210, server: mysite.com, request: "GET /media/attach_1/attach.pdf HTTP/1.1", host: "mysite.com", referrer: "mysite.com/app2/"*

**Nginx conf**:

```
 server {
            listen 80;
            server_name server_domain;
            location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

            location /static/ {
                    root /home/user/app1;
            }
            location /app2/static/ {
                root /home/user;
            }

            location /media/ {
                root /home/user/app1;
             }
            location /app2/media/ {
                root /home/user;
            }

            location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/run/app1.sock;
            }
            location /secondapp/ {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/run/app2.sock:/;
            }
        }
```

**app2.settings**:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
```

I also have `urlpatterns = [...] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to @0p3r4t0r answer, you should made the following changes in your `nginx.conf`:

```
    location /app2/static/ {
        root /home/user/;
    }
    location /app2/media/ {
        root /home/user/;
    }
```

And even this would work only if your `app2` URI prefix is the same as the name of your `app2` folder. Otherwise you'll need an `alias` directive:

```
    location /app2/static/ {
        alias /home/user/app2/static/;
    }
    location /app2/media/ {
        alias /home/user/app2/media/;
    }
```

But if they are the same, the first config is preferable.

Comment: My app2 URI is the same as folder name, but unfortunately both options didn't work. Still 404, though nginx error log doesn't show the error anymore.

Comment: @Alina I'm sorry for the copy/paste error. Remove the `=` sign from all locations except the `location = /favicon.ico { ... }`.

Comment: I removed it respectively. Still same error. I updated my question with the current config I have.

Comment: One more attempt: add slash to the end of `root` directive path parameters as I did in my answer. Test it and show last entries from the error log.

Answer (score 1):

For app2 shouldn't you change you media and static urls to point to the urls for app2 on your server?

```py
STATIC_URL = '/app2/static/'
...
MEDIA_URL = '/app2/media/'
```

As it stands they are pointing to the same URLs you're using for app1, which would explain why the URLs are valid, but the wrong directory is being searched for your files.

Comment: I changed it accordingly. Unfortunately it doesn't help.